# Javascript evaluating undefined expressions in OR statement

Tags: javascript

So I have a statement that looks like this

```
subsetSumArray[i][j]=(subsetSumArray[i-1][j] || subsetSumArray[i-1][j-arr[i]]);
```

The problem is that when variable j is less than arr[i], subsetSumArray[i-1][j-arr[i]] will return undefined. If subsetSumArray is undefined I would like it to be treated as false. Whats the shortest way to do this. 
So basically I'd want it to work like this 
(*some undefined variable* || true) ===> return true

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: At least in Chrome, (undefined || true) -> true as `undefined` is naturally falsey.

Comment: `subsetSumArray[i][j] = subsetSumArray[i-1][j] || subsetSumArray[i-1][j-arr[i]] || false;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest way is to do a *double negative* (`!!`) trick:

```
subsetSumArray[i][j]=!!(subsetSumArray[i-1][j] || subsetSumArray[i-1][j-arr[i]]);
```

See the below code and run it:

```js
// empty array
var a = [];
// var[1] is undefined
alert( a[1] );                // undefined
alert(!! a[1] );              // false
alert(a[1] || true);          // true
alert( a[1] || a[2] );        // undefined
alert( !! (a[1] || a[2]) );   // false
```

Answer (score -1):

Problem is, `||` doesn't work with variables that **aren't defined or undeclared** so you have to use `typeof`, **not in your case though** but again, if the variable isn't defined yet.

```
subsetSumArray[i][j] = (typeof subsetSumArray[i-1][j] !== 'undefined' ? subsetSumArray[i-1][j] : subsetSumArray[i-1][j - arr[i]]);
```

That said, shorthands is this case are unreadable:

```
if (typeof subsetSumArray[i-1][j] !== 'undefined')
    subsetSumArray[i][j] = subsetSumArray[i - 1][j];
else
    subsetSumArray[i][j] = subsetSumArray[i-1][j - arr[i]];
```

That is valid and a lot easier to understand what is going on. You can even remove the newlines

---

If you have never mentioned a variable or it isn't defined, you will need to use `typeof`

```
function foo (o) {
    var baz = o.bar || 'hello';
    return baz;
}
foo(); // throws error
```

Comment: @PM77-1 it works, may not be the shortest way but it solves the problem

Comment: The top statement is wrong. There's nothing wrong with using `||` with `undefined` values. It works.

Comment: @PM77-1 it doesn't work with undefined statements, you're making it a false statement. It' so's damn annoying at how negative Stack Overflow is,

Comment: @PM77-1 yes but my answer works, doesn't it? It's wrong, you just don't like it. Your answer is more misleading promoting the idea that un-declared variables work just fine. With your solution it'll throw an error

Comment: Your answer contains a false statement.  OP does **not** have to use `typeof`.

Comment: @vihan1086, that's simply not true. `var x = {}; if (x.undef || true) console.log('hi');` logs "hi" with no complaints whatsoever.

Comment: @GabrielLebec I've noted that **not in OPs case** but with **undeclared (NOT undefined)** variables. You have to bold things for people to understand things around here...

Comment: Perhaps if you could illustrate an example of when `||` "doesn't work" your point would be clearer.

Comment: @GabrielLebec that would, I've added that.

Comment: I see what you're trying to say. That's not an issue of `||`, that's an issue of attempting to access a property of an undefined variable. That throws an error in any context — including your example, which fails. Try it yourself, `var obj = {}; typeof obj.foo.bar === undefined;` throws an error.

Comment: @GabrielLebec yeah, my point was that `typeof` would be the way to deal with it. Also if it's a function you'll get errors

Comment: But… as I just illustrated, `typeof` does NOT work. It throws an error just as || does or anything else. Actually it's not the operator that's the issue, it's attempting to access a property of undefined. That will always throw an error, no matter what. There is no way around it except testing for definition in a serial way: `if (o && o.prop && o.prop.p2 && o.prop.p2.p3)` or similar (short circuiting if any of the steps in the chain is undefined).

Comment: @GabrielLebec hm, that's right. The main reason I use typeof is for functions